# Why does mutate() give me an error that I should use integer vector while using integer vector?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

```
new_data<-new_data%>%
  mutate(dd=case_when(
    edu_yr402==95 ~ NA_integer_,
    edu_yr402==93|edu_yr402==94 ~ 1, 
    TRUE~edu_yr402))
```

I swear edu_yr402 is an integer vector.
I checked it with > class(new_data$edu_yr402)
[1] "integer"
However, error message is as follows:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `dd`.
x must be an integer vector, not a double vector.
i Input `dd` is `case_when(...)`.

one Commenter said dd becomes logical vector since I put NA in the first string. Thus, I tried

```
new_data<-new_data%>%
  mutate(dd=case_when(
    edu_yr402==93|edu_yr402==94 ~ 1, 
    TRUE~edu_yr402,
    edu_yr402==95 ~ NA_integer_))
```

but it gives me error ...

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `dd`.
x must be a double vector, not an integer vector.
i Input `dd` is `case_when(...)`.

Comment: The issue is that your column dd is consider as `logical` since the first argument in `case_when` throws an `NA`. Therefor, it expects all the next possible values to be logical.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Thus, I tried new_data<-new_data%>%
  mutate(dd=case_when(
    edu_yr402==93|edu_yr402==94 ~ 1, 
    TRUE~edu_yr402,
    edu_yr402==95 ~ NA_integer_)), but it gives me another error..:Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `dd`.
x must be a double vector, not an integer vector.
i Input `dd` is `case_when(...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility to overcome this conflict:

In your console type `?case_when` then see the help file:

Here `1L` makes `1` to be integer. then you can use `NA_integer_` which is the integer type of `NA`

```
new_data<-new_data%>%
  mutate(dd=case_when(
    edu_yr402==95 ~ NA_integer_,
    edu_yr402==93|edu_yr402==94 ~ 1L, 
    TRUE~as.integer(edu_yr402)))
```

Here `as.numeric` version

```
new_data<-new_data%>%
  mutate(dd=case_when(
    edu_yr402==95 ~ NA_real_,
    edu_yr402==93|edu_yr402==94 ~ 1, 
    TRUE~as.numeric(edu_yr402)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments ! Is there any reason that I cannot use integer type ? edu_yr402 is a integer vector, so I am not sure why I should use NA_real_, rather than NA_integer_.

Comment: you can use `integer` by adding an `L` to `~1`. I will update.

Comment: Many thanks for your kind reply and comments! It helped me alot

Answer (score 3):

As I mentionned, the problem is you have different types of output in a type-strict function (`case_when`). So it throws you an error. You can do this to resolve it:

```
new_data%>%
  mutate(dd=case_when(
    edu_yr402==95 ~ as.double(NA),
    edu_yr402==93|edu_yr402==94 ~ 1, 
    TRUE~edu_yr402))
```

If you want to have integers anyway:

```
new_data%>%
  mutate(dd=case_when(
    edu_yr402==95 ~ NA_integer_,
    edu_yr402==93|edu_yr402==94 ~ 1L, 
    TRUE~as.integer(edu_yr402)))
```

Edit: used 1L instead of `as.integer(1)` as TarJae suggested

Comment: Thanks for your comments! but It generates errors..  case_when() is type-strict function, however,edu_yr402 is integer so I am really curious why we should use double..

Comment: Can't tell without a data sample of `edu_yr402`. Please see the edit if you want to keep the data as integer anyway

Comment: Many thanks for your kind reply and comments! It was really helpful!